# Has there been research done on the dependence of particle decay to its immediate surroundings?

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, weak-interaction, mesons, pions

The meson particle, Kaon, can decay into pions or leptons + neutrinos. Each decay has its own probabilities as measured and confirmed during experiments.

Has there been any research into the possibility that Kaon particle decay or any particle decay depend on its own surroundings?

There is Bell's theorem and the Hidden-variable theory that addresses whether or this decay or any QM process is truly random, but I interpret in the material Ive read that the search for the hidden variable or the assumption of Bell's theorem is that the missing parameter is an attribute of the particle itself. No reading material that I know of addresses the possibility of external dependence, and so this is why Im asking the question. I don't read professional journals or academic textbooks to know the general view on this but I think its an obvious enough of a question to have been looked into or straight out shot down due to some obvious reason that I dont know of.

An answer in the form of "See this article" would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> Has there been any research into the possibility that Kaon particle decay or any particle decay depend on its own surroundings?

"its own surroundings" in field theory is defined by the quantum fields a particle traverses. So in physics terms you are asking "whether lifetimes measured for unstable particles would depend on the fields traversed".

Would  this be  an example of what  you are asking about?

> [The lifetime of unstable particles in electromagnetic fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.0377)

> We show that the electromagnetic moments of unstable particles (resonances) have an absorptive contribution which quantifies the change of the particle's lifetime in an external electromagnetic field. To give an example we compute here the imaginary part of the magnetic moment for the cases of the muon and the neutron at leading order in the electroweak coupling.

In their conclusions:

> In all the three considered cases the effect on the lifetime is tiny for normal magnetic fields: in a uniform field of 1 Tesla the change in the lifetime is of orderof $10^{−13}percent$, at most.

So theorists have been thinking on similar lines, and in this particular example the answer is yes, to a tiny unmeasurable in lab effect.

Comment: I was thinking something more local when I said immediate. Something not necessarily far field as they'd say for decribing EM fields for an antenna. More or less whether or not other particles in the particle soup affect ond another. Nice example tho. Can you update to state if there is anything more local that you know of?

Comment: ". More or less whether or not other particles in the particle soup affect ond another. ". Of course particles within interaction range  of  decay/interaction will be a different more rare decay/interaction and will be described with different  Feynman diagrams giving different results. There are hundreds of them.

Answer (score 0):

Lindstrom and collaborators (2010, [free on arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.5071), [expensive in NIM](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.nima.2010.06.270)) examined whether the decay of gold-198 depends on the local (anti)neutrino flux, by making gold sources shaped either as spheres or as flat foils.  From the foil, most of the decay antineutrinos escape the gold straightaway; from the sphere, somewhat more than half of the antineutrinos have to travel through the gold before escaping into the vacuum.  (I don't see the ratio of the two antineutrino fluxes on a quick skim, but I remember it being many orders of magnitude.  The results were consistent with no effect.  There's a bibliography.